# Rails 3.0.9 Routing error - how to fix - to meet the goal of using /registration/diagnoses as a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

## Background

I have attended an excellent Rails course in Manchester, UK recently run at MadLabs (plug for them) run by two knowledgable practicioners.

Prior to that I have worked my way through several notable books:

- Ryan Biggs et al's 'Rails 3 in Action'
- Pragmatic Book 'Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition'
- I originally started with Michael Hartl's excellent screencasts/book.

All of these are great starting places, but then we venture into the real world!

I have spent the best part of 2 days googling how to fix this, and still haven't had much luck with multiple errors occurring.

As a newcomer to this wonderful language, I'm keen to learn, and realise that this is probably a stupid question to all the seasoned developers. BUT, we all have to start somewhere.

I could take the easy route and just stick with the resources option, but think this will get unwieldy with 15 Registration activities.

Any suggestions greatfuly received.

I hope in time to be able to contribute answers myself.

Thanks in advance.

### The problem

I'm working on a personal learning project porting a VB6 application to Rails (3.0.9)

In the existing application there are a number of 'Registration' type activities. e.g. staff, stock, user, laboratory tests, diagnosis, etc (15 all up)

Currently having an issue with routing whereby I have removed the scaffolding generated resource in an attempt to make a more generic resource later for all the other registrations. Whether this involves nesting or use of namespaces I am not sure.

### Aspiration

However I wanted to be able to use a URL such as: /registration/
e.g. /registration/diagnosis (or es, still figuring out the singular/plural detail)

My routes file looks as follows:

```
# resources :diagnoses

match '/registration/diagnosis', :to => 'diagnoses#new', :as => :new_diagnosis
```

The diagnoses controller looks as follows:

```
class DiagnosesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @diagnosis = Diagnosis.new
  end

end
```

The diagnoses form partial looks as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@diagnosis) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :code %>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %>        
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### Error message

```
NoMethodError in Diagnoses#new

Showing /Users/rails3dev/railsprojects/myhospapp1/app/views/diagnoses/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `diagnoses_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001028a9f50>:0x0000010289ebf0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@diagnosis) do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.error_messages %>
3:   <p>
4:  <%= f.label :code %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/diagnoses/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/rails3dev/railsprojects/myhospapp1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/diagnoses/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_diagnoses__form_html_erb__1092201988075669766_2168688260_2510900908163010427'
app/views/diagnoses/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_diagnoses_new_html_erb__2033770677348794944_2168763160_2124755090121635792'
```

#### Looking for answers on:

1. How do I fix this error to meet the goal of using
   /registration/diagnoses?
2. Is it generally a good idea to have multiple activities
       (registration types) under the /registrations (I'm going to call it
       path)? If so is this achieved by using namespaces?
3. How does one debug the content in the line - undefined method `diagnoses_path' for #<#:0x0000010289ebf0>

Comment: Just to help me get my head round this... when you say registration do you mean you're creating a new (diagnosis, stock item, etc)?

Comment: yes, thats right. So effectively using the new (or create) actions (assuming I'm using the HTTP verbs correctly).

Comment: Also forgot to add the line from the _header partial that wants to use the /registration/diagnosis
`<li><%= link_to "Diagnosis Registration", registration_diagnosis_path %></li>` (amongst others I have tried)

Comment: What's the value in using registration at the first level in the URL?  Also my (limited) understanding is that the standard RESTFUL URL convention used is to have the resource and then the action.  Would /diagnosis/register not be a more meaningful URL?

Comment: Not coming from a web background I figured it would be best to have all the registration type activities under one URL which effictively mapped to one drop down menu (probably only accessible by those with specific permissions) - hence going for /registration/<type>

Comment: Well I'm fully prepared for someone more experienced to say I'm wrong but I think that's backwards to the way rails expects you to work.  Are you based in Manchester?

Comment: No was just there for the excellent course, and trying to apply some of the learning to a personal project. So are we saying that for the 15 registration type activities I will end up with 15 controllers/15 models & 15 folders under views? Or is this where I can make greater use of partials?

Comment: I thought the whole point of the match section in routing was to be able to create your own routes. Is this bashful optimism/youthful inexperience?